# Exclude Multiple ID's from MySQL query

Tags: mysql

Hoping this is just a case of syntax.

I'm writing a custom search function for Wordpress and it's all working great except I'd like to exclude a couple of results dependant on their ID's.

This works ok with one ID

```
$sqlp_page ="select ID, post_title, post_name, post_excerpt from wp_posts where post_type='page' and ID != '236' ";
$sqlp_page .="and post_status='publish' ";
$sqlp_page .="and (post_title like '%".$_GET['s']."%' ";
$sqlp_page .="or post_content like '%".$_GET['s']."%') ";
$sqlp_page .="and post_status='publish' ";
$sqlp_page .="order by id ASC ";
```

But I can't seem to pass in more than one value for the ID.
I have searched the net and tried several different ways but nothing seems to work for me.

```
$sqlp_page ="select ID, post_title, post_name, post_excerpt from wp_posts where post_type='page' and ID != '236,239' ";
```

Or

```
$sqlp_page ="select ID, post_title, post_name, post_excerpt from wp_posts where post_type='page' and ID != '236' or '239' ";
```

And

```
$sqlp_page .="and ID != '236' ";
$sqlp_page .="and ID != '239' ";
```

But nothing seems to work. 
Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't you use `WHERE ID IN('1', '5', '235');`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`NOT IN`](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/in.php):

```
$sqlp_page ="select ID, post_title, post_name, post_excerpt 
from wp_posts where post_type='page' and ID NOT IN ('236','239') ";
```

Inside `NOT IN`, you need to separate multiple `ID` values with a comma.